# D3 axis tick overlapping with bars

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg

I generate a chart with d3, and the problem is this ugly effect due to the overlapping between the bottom tick and the bars.

[image]

**Zoom**

[image]

I first draw the bars and then generate the axis, so the ticks should always be on the top of the bar (on the "z" dimension, considering there is no concept of z-index in svg) and hide this effect.
 But this is never the case, I'm not sure if this is an svg or d3 problem.

Her's what I basically do (pseudocode and missing parts):

```
// define scales
xScale
    .domain(d3.range(0, xMax))
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], 0.2, 0.2)

yScale
    .domain([0, yMax])
    .range([height, 0])

// draw bars
d3.
    .selectAll(".bar")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
        .append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bar")

// draw the y axis (with long horizontal ticks)
yAxis
    .orient('left')
    .ticks(10)
    .tickPadding(15)
    .tickSize(-width)

d3.selectAll(g.axis-y)
    .attr("transform", "translate(0, 0)")
    .call(yAxis)
```

I realize that if I ask the entire group "axis-y" to be on an higher z level of the bars then all the ticks will overlap the bars (not what I want).
**What I want**: the bottom tick to be on an higher level of the bars in order to hide the ugly effect (or an alternative solution to reach the same result)

**EDIT:** even tough I draw the axis later, I add it to a `g` group that was created before the bars, so in fact the axis is on a lower level.

Comment: If you don't find an easier way to do this... you could put a clipping region over the bars, or have two y axes one for the grid and one for the actual axis.

Comment: Why dont you offset the bar by half the height of your bottom tick? If you add a fiddle maybe we can help.

Comment: You may be adding the axis to a `g` element that was added before the bars.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff, yes, indeed. But if I change the order then all the ticks will overlap the bars, I would like only the last one to be on top of the bars. Or an alternative solution

Comment: @AndyLewis it is D3 that generates the ticks so I don't have much control on the height (supposed to be stroke-width) of the line. Also, even if we are talking about 1 or 2 pixels this will shift everything and things won't be pixel perfect anymore

Comment: Your values are decimals to two significant figures so the pixel perfectness of the drawing is surely somewhat moot? I would certainly expect a few pixels nudge (half the tick line width) wouldn't make all that much difference to your chart. Add a plunker or fiddle so we can have a play too.

Comment: @AndyLewis In this case you are right, but I was looking for a more general solution that doesn't imply shifting everything up just to fix this little problem